# Mapping same DB column to different fields/properties of subclasses in Hibernate when using table per hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, persistence

I have a base (abstract) class A and two subclasses B and C which I want to persist them using table-per-hierarchy approach in Hibernate. Suppose B has 'width' and C has 'height' field which are of the same type. By default Hibernate creates two separate columns but fills only one column for each row. Now, what happens if I map both fields to the same column in DB, say 'length'?

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class B extends A {
    @Column(name="length")
    public Integer width;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class C extends A {
    @Column(name="length")
    public Integer height;
}
```

I ran some basic tests and no error happened, but I didn't see anything like this in documentations -considering this practice prevents creation of lots of empty columns in a complex application and should be mentioned - and really don't have the expertise to declare this as a safe practice.

Has anyone done something like this? Are there any drawbacks to this approach? Also does the no-NOT-NULL-on-subclasses limitation holds in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not encountered any problems after using this method for two years in production.

But notice that you cannot set different restrictions on fields because database sees them as one column.